# error mysqli_insert_id can't insert and delete

Tags: php

Case : use mysqli_insert_id to INSERT into table orders_detail and DELETE on table orders_temp
Error : Can't INSERT into table orders_detail and DELETE on table orders_detail

Structure table :

```
orders = id_oders [int] Primary Key AUTO_INCREMENT
orders_detail = id_orders[int] (No Primary Key, No AUTO_INCREMENT)
orders_temp = id_orders_temp[int] Primary Key AUTO_INCREMENT
```

here my code :

```
$tgl_skrg = date("Ymd");
$jam_skrg = date("H:i:s");

$id = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,  "SELECT id_kustomer FROM kustomer WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'"));

// mendapatkan nomor kustomer
$id_kustomer=$id[id_kustomer];

// simpan data pemesanan
$query_order = mysqli_query($con,  "INSERT INTO orders(tgl_order,jam_order,id_kustomer) VALUES('$tgl_skrg','$jam_skrg','$id_kustomer')") ;


// mendapatkan nomor orders
$id_orders=mysqli_insert_id($con, $query_order);

// panggil fungsi isi_keranjang dan hitung jumlah produk yang dipesan
$isikeranjang = isi_keranjang();
$jml          = count($isikeranjang);

// simpan data detail pemesanan  
for ($i = 0; $i < $jml; $i++){
  mysqli_query($con,  "INSERT INTO orders_detail(id_orders, id_produk, jumlah)
              VALUES('$id_orders',{$isikeranjang[$i]['id_produk']}, {$isikeranjang[$i]['jumlah']})") or die(mysqli_error());
}

// setelah data pemesanan tersimpan, hapus data pemesanan di tabel pemesanan sementara (orders_temp)
for ($i = 0; $i < $jml; $i++) {
  mysqli_query($con,  "DELETE FROM orders_temp
              WHERE id_orders_temp = {$isikeranjang[$i]['id_orders_temp']}") or die(mysqli_error());
}
```

Comment: try adding `printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));`  after your mysqli_query lines

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: Or show us ALL the error messages from `die(mysqli_error())`

Comment: Who upvotes bad questions like this. _Please stop_

Comment: thanks riggfolly, it's worked :D